# TotalCommander Поиск в файле по двум словам

Tags: поиск, totalcommander

Как реализовать поиск по двум или более словам? `|`, `,` или `OR` не работают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Включить опцию "Регулярные выражения"
2. Использовать в качестве разделителя символ `|`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то не работает с &&, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov у меня работает, соответственно, надо больше подробностей и, возможно, новый вопрос.